# Emulate row count on 2 columns in Access

Tags: ms-access, window-functions

I have the following table in Access

[image]

I have a number of lines where there are duplicates when you filter on the first and second column. I need to remove these duplicates. The best way I found is to use `row_number`.

I want to emulate the equivalent of this Postgres query in Microsoft Access:

```
SELECT 
    "Supplier_code", 
    "Internal_reference", 
    "Supplier_reference", 
    "Family_code", 
    "Purchasing_unit", 
    "Purchasing_price",
    "Purchasing_currency",
    "Consigned",
    "Eco_order_qty",
    "Pack_order_qty",
    "Min_order_qty",
    "Min_order_value",
    "Product_grossweight",
    "Product_grosscube",
    "Leadtime_days",
    "Supplier_active",
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "Supplier_code", "Internal_reference" 
ORDER BY "Internal_reference") AS "cnt"
FROM dw.T13_RefSupplier_Mexico_ToXL
```

I had a look on the internet and I found this on Stack Overflow but I'm not sure where to start:

- [Achieving ROW_NUMBER / PARTITION BY in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21917637)

This table is a buffer table and has no PK. All duplicate data must be purged from this table. Once done, it will go to the main table where `Supplier_code` & `Internal_reference`are part of the PK.

I built this query but it does not achieve what I want:

```
 SELECT 
    t1.Supplier_code,
    t1.Internal_reference,
    t1.Supplier_reference,
    t1.Family_code,
    t1.Purchasing_unit,
    t1.Purchasing_price,
    t1.Purchasing_currency,
    t1.Consigned,
    t1.Eco_order_qty,
    t1.Pack_order_qty,
    t1.Min_order_qty,
    t1.Min_order_value,
    t1.Product_grossweight,
    t1.Product_grosscube,
    t1.Leadtime_days,
    t1.Supplier_active,
    COUNT(*) AS [Ino]
FROM 
    T13_RefSupplier_Mexico_ToXL AS t1
    INNER JOIN
    T13_RefSupplier_Mexico_ToXL AS t2
        ON t2.Supplier_code = t1.Supplier_code
            AND t2.Purchasing_price <= t1.Purchasing_price
GROUP BY
    t1.Supplier_code,
    t1.Internal_reference,
    t1.Supplier_reference,
    t1.Family_code,
    t1.Purchasing_unit,
    t1.Purchasing_price,
    t1.Purchasing_currency,
    t1.Consigned,
    t1.Eco_order_qty,
    t1.Pack_order_qty,
    t1.Min_order_qty,
    t1.Min_order_value,
    t1.Product_grossweight,
    t1.Product_grosscube,
    t1.Leadtime_days,
    t1.Supplier_active
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Please find an extract of my data below

```
Supplier_code;Internal_reference;Supplier_reference;Family_code;Purchasing_unit;Purchasing_price;Purchasing_currency;Consigned;Eco_order_qty;Pack_order_qty;Min_order_qty;Min_order_value;Product_grossweight;Product_grosscube;Leadtime_days;Supplier_active;
T040;16-0022;;401;EA;0.072;USD;0;0;;;;;;42;1;
T040;50-0595A;;401;EA;0.163;USD;0;0;;;;;;42;1;
T070;50-0672;;131;EA;0.0693;USD;0;0;;;;;;63;1;
T070;50-0673;;131;EA;0.0755;USD;0;0;;;;;;63;1;
T070;50-0687;;131;EA;0.1097;USD;0;0;;;;;;63;1;
T070;50-0688;;131;EA;0.0899;USD;0;0;;;;;;63;1;
T070;50-0738;;131;EA;0.124;USD;0;0;;;;;;0;1;
T080;16-0067;;402;EA;0.47;EUR;0;0;;;;;;0;1;
T080;16-0067;;402;EA;0.47;USD;0;0;;;;;;0;1;
T900;53-2008;;391;EA;0.039;USD;0;0;;;;;;63;1;
T900;53-2008;;391;EA;0.033;USD;0;0;;;;;;63;1;
```

The desired result can either be the solution, where the duplicates are removed

```
Supplier_code;Internal_reference;Supplier_reference;Family_code;Purchasing_unit;Purchasing_price;Purchasing_currency;Consigned;Eco_order_qty;Pack_order_qty;Min_order_qty;Min_order_value;Product_grossweight;Product_grosscube;Leadtime_days;Supplier_active;
    T040;16-0022;;401;EA;0.072;USD;0;0;;;;;;42;1;
    T040;50-0595A;;401;EA;0.163;USD;0;0;;;;;;42;1;
    T070;50-0672;;131;EA;0.0693;USD;0;0;;;;;;63;1;
    T070;50-0673;;131;EA;0.0755;USD;0;0;;;;;;63;1;
    T070;50-0687;;131;EA;0.1097;USD;0;0;;;;;;63;1;
    T070;50-0688;;131;EA;0.0899;USD;0;0;;;;;;63;1;
    T070;50-0738;;131;EA;0.124;USD;0;0;;;;;;0;1;
    T080;16-0067;;402;EA;0.47;EUR;0;0;;;;;;0;1;
    T900;53-2008;;391;EA;0.039;USD;0;0;;;;;;63;1;
```

Or the solution where the duplicates are flagged

```
Supplier_code;Internal_reference;Supplier_reference;Family_code;Purchasing_unit;Purchasing_price;Purchasing_currency;Consigned;Eco_order_qty;Pack_order_qty;Min_order_qty;Min_order_value;Product_grossweight;Product_grosscube;Leadtime_days;Supplier_active;Duplicate
T040;16-0022;;401;EA;0.072;USD;0;0;;;;;;42;1;1
T040;50-0595A;;401;EA;0.163;USD;0;0;;;;;;42;1;1
T070;50-0672;;131;EA;0.0693;USD;0;0;;;;;;63;1;1
T070;50-0673;;131;EA;0.0755;USD;0;0;;;;;;63;1;1
T070;50-0687;;131;EA;0.1097;USD;0;0;;;;;;63;1;1
T070;50-0688;;131;EA;0.0899;USD;0;0;;;;;;63;1;1
T070;50-0738;;131;EA;0.124;USD;0;0;;;;;;0;1;1
T080;16-0067;;402;EA;0.47;EUR;0;0;;;;;;0;1;1
T080;16-0067;;402;EA;0.47;USD;0;0;;;;;;0;1;2
T900;53-2008;;391;EA;0.039;USD;0;0;;;;;;63;1;1
T900;53-2008;;391;EA;0.033;USD;0;0;;;;;;63;1;2
```

I cannot create an autoincrement in my query as it is not a real table, more the results of a query. See the picture in Access:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "triangular" self-join and group by or - the equivalent - inline self-join and count should work (but I'm not really sure if it fails due to some Access restrictions):

```
SELECT 
    t.*,
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
      FROM dw.T13_RefSupplier_Mexico_ToXL AS c
      WHERE       -- PARTITION BY these 2 columns 
            c."Supplier_code" = t."Supplier_code" 
        AND c."Internal_reference" = t."Internal_reference" 
                  -- ORDER BY these 2
        AND ( c."Purchasing_currency" < t."Purchasing_currency" 
           OR (  c."Purchasing_currency" = t."Purchasing_currency" 
             AND c."Purchasing_price" <= t."Purchasing_price"
              )
            )
    ) AS cnt
FROM 
    dw.T13_RefSupplier_Mexico_ToXL AS t ;
```

Answer (score 2):

IMHO you don't need a simulated ROW_NUMBER function just to avoid duplicates, you can easily get it by adding a unique field, in this case an AUTO-INCREMENT field. If you cannot made it PRIMARY KEY, at least set an index on it without duplicates.

Let's name this field ID.

Then you can use a view or a subquery that returns `MIN(ID)` grouped by `Supplier_code; Internal_reference`

```
SELECT   Min(ID) as ID, Supplier_code, Internal_reference
FROM     T13_RefSupplier_Mexico_ToXL
GROUP BY Supplier_code, Internal_reference
```

Last step, JOIN this view with your current query:

```
SELECT     ...
FROM       T13_RefSupplier_Mexico_ToXL t1
INNER JOIN TheNewView nv
ON         t1.ID = nv.ID
AND        t1.Supplier_code = nv.Supplier_code
AND        t1.Internal_reference = nv.Internal_reference
```

I've set up a small MS-Access project with the provided data, and it works fine.

[image]